# Windows: Slideshow of all pictures in a directory but with various display durations

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, irfanview, autoit, mpv

All pictures in a folder should be displayed automatically one after the other = Slideshow. The tricky part is that most of the pictures should be displayed for 20 seconds each and a few others should be displayed for 40, 50 or 60 seconds.

All pictures file names end with one of the numbers 20, 40, 50, 60 indicating the time to be displayed.

Persons with basic IT skills add new pictures to the given directory and name them accordingly. A script should display the pictures automatically when the computer starts; it is used as a simple kiosk system and there are no othere tasks for that system.

I know there are tons of digital signage apps available but none of our staff could handle them.
Which viewer program would fit my needs?

Is FFPlay the perfect tool? If yes, could someone give a little help with a script?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please note that superuser.com is not a free script/code/homework writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code/calculations you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How to Ask](https://superuser.com/questions/how-to-ask).